# Using phonegap database API with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create and Android application with jQuery / Phonegap using the source found here: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-using-the-phonegap-database-api/

However, when deployed, the list from the database does not show up.

Based on the sample on the site it should work, am I missing something?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd recommend doing some basic debugging. See if there are any errors being thrown that you may be missing. Also - I've got an example of Phonegap/DB support here: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/10/20/Example-of-PhoneGaps-Database-Support

Maybe this alternative example will help.

Comment: Cool. The application worked but adding "note" don't work? I mean, even if I added a note it does not show it.

Comment: If you can, post a comment on the blog entry and we can take the discussion there. I have a few things I'd like you to check.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the dml file that populates the database?